# Print Doesn't Work in WebView on android kotiln

Tags: java, android, kotlin, web-applications, webview

he following example code from here works fine in both the default browser "Internet" and "Chrome" browser on android.

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>




<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

\<button onclick="myFunction()"\>Print this page\</button\>


function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
```

However when hosted inside a WebView, nothing happens when clicking "Print this page"

My view XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kotlin has the following:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.print.PrintAttributes
import android.print.PrintManager
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.print.PrintHelper





class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        val webSettings: WebSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        webView.loadUrl("http://10.10.0.10:3112/")


    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_PRINT_JOB_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The WebView developer documentation here explicitly calls out:

You cannot use JavaScript in a HTML document to trigger printing.

How can I host a webpage and allow JavaScript printing to work.

Alternatives I've thought of but haven't found a way to implement:

Intercept button clicks, if Print button is been clicked trigger my own printing code
Replace the "Print" button HTML on the fly with some other code that would allow me to handle it in my application
So far to workaround this limitation I've added "Print" button to my application and run my own printing code. It works fine, but is confusing user experience as "Print" button in web page does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To print a WebView with a print button in Kotlin using View Binding, you can follow these steps:

1. In your layout XML file, add a WebView and a Button for printing:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/print_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Print"/>
```

2. In your activity or fragment, initialize the WebView and Button using View Binding:

```
private lateinit var binding: YourLayoutBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = YourLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val webView = binding.webView
    val printButton = binding.printButton
    ...
}
```

3. Load your desired URL in the WebView:

```
webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com")
```

4. Define a print function that creates a PrintManager and prints the WebView:

```
private fun printWebView() {
    val printManager = getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
    val printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter()
    printManager.print("Print WebView", printAdapter, PrintAttributes.Builder().build())
}
```

5. Set an OnClickListener for the print button that calls the print function:

```
printButton.setOnClickListener {
    printWebView()
}
```

Your final code should look something like this:

```
private lateinit var binding: YourLayoutBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = YourLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val webView = binding.webView
    val printButton = binding.printButton

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com")

    printButton.setOnClickListener {
        printWebView()
    }
}

private fun printWebView() {
    val printManager = getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
    val printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter()
    printManager.print("Print WebView", printAdapter, PrintAttributes.Builder().build())
}
```

Comment: what YourLayoutBinding ? where

Comment: @hadi you have to fill in your info (YourLayout) is the name of your layout